# LGSideMenuController for Android

Tags: android

There is a library in Github for iOS called [LGSideMenuController](https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGSideMenuController). I am looking for exactly similar effect for Android Navigation drawer. Is there any similar library for Android.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this

**onCreate**

```
 // attach to current activity;
    resideMenu = new ResideMenu(this);
    resideMenu.setBackground(R.drawable.menu_background);
    resideMenu.attachToActivity(this);

    // create menu items;
    String titles[] = { "Home", "Profile", "Calendar", "Settings" };
    int icon[] = { R.drawable.icon_home, R.drawable.icon_profile, R.drawable.icon_calendar, R.drawable.icon_settings };

    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++){
        ResideMenuItem item = new ResideMenuItem(this, icon[i], titles[i]);
        item.setOnClickListener(this);
        resideMenu.addMenuItem(item,  ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT); // or  ResideMenu.DIRECTION_RIGHT
    }
```

**open/close menu**

```
resideMenu.openMenu(ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT); // or ResideMenu.DIRECTION_RIGHT
resideMenu.closeMenu();
```

**menu state**

```
 resideMenu.setMenuListener(menuListener);
private ResideMenu.OnMenuListener menuListener = new ResideMenu.OnMenuListener() {
    @Override
    public void openMenu() {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Menu is opened!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void closeMenu() {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Menu is closed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

[image]

Please refer the below link for more details

https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=708

Comment: Thank you @arya for your post. Actually i was going through this library and  few queries came into my mind.

Comment: 1)Is there a way to make the Main Activity screen bigger when it slides. Presently it looks very small.  2)How can i add navigation header to this layout